# Jquery on 'click' event working for one selected id but not both

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

I'm having a strange issue I don't understand, I've been working on a webpage on which I can download images taken from a webcam or phone camera. Since the beginning, I used a  tag with a "download" text that I clicked on in order to to download the image (taken from an example). But now that I implemented it, I want to change the  to a real button, and now my click event doesn't work.

Here is the html of the two elements:-

```
<a id="download" >Download as image</a>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="ag_photo_download_button">Download Photo</button>
```

and the js used for the event:-

```
$('#download,#ag_photo_download_button').on('click',function(){code of my function});
```

What I find really odd is that the event is triggered when I click on the "Download as image", but not on my Download photo.

Also, what is even more strange is that if I put this code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8x95nf2/) in works perfectly, but not in my code. Plus this is the only function linked to those elements.

I'd like to put the complete code for my page but the camera part occurs after I made a few queries to a database so it won't work in jsfiddle, I hope you could help me anyway.

Edit : Second [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8x95nf2/1/) with more code 
Edit 2 : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8x95nf2/2/) with full code

Comment: do you declare the function before the button is rendered to screen? try    `$(document).on("click","#download,#ag_photo_download_button",function(){});`

Comment: Can you post all your code, it's fine it it doesn't run as it doesn't seem like we can find out why it's not working with what you've provided. Thanks

Comment: *"if i put this code in jsfiddle in works perfectly, but not in my code"* This is the give away that the issue has to do with some other code on your page that is conflicting with this code here.

Comment: my function is declared after the $(document).ready(function(){  part. I tried your code but it's not working either :/

Comment: have your tried `$(document).on( "click", '#download,#ag_photo_download_button', function() {}` ?

Comment: if you can't replicate your problem in a fiddle, how can we help you ? the problem is surely with some other parts of code. check your console and re-check all your code again ( check also for duplicate IDs )

Comment: I edited my post with the full code in Fiddle

Comment: @MihaiT Fiddle is not the only way to solve problems, it could happen that  someone just goes like " oh i already had this issue, check if (..) "

Comment: Just for kicks, I would add a new, unique class to both elements and then change your selector to just that class and see what happens.

Comment: Nice idea, but i get the same result, the button doesn't work and the text does :/

Comment: Ok, next I would validate your HTML and CSS (http://validator.w3.org and https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ to make sure that a stupid syntax error isn't preventing the HTML from being parsed or the CSS from being read.

Comment: I had a spare </div> that i deleted, but i still get the same results, also i have this error with the validator : Error: Duplicate attribute class. but i guess it's ok since it's on purpose that we have 2 elements in the same class  ?

Comment: That error means that you have the `class` attribute twice on one element, like this: `<a class="test" class="test2">`, which is not allowed. If you want to apply more than one class to an element, just list the classes, separated by a space, as in: `<a class="test test2">`

Comment: Oh okay i didn't know it wasn't allowed, i corrected it. I ain't got no errors now but my button still doesn't want to execute my function :(

Answer (score -1):

Why are you dont trying to call your function direct in your button  ?

```html
<a id="download" >Download as image</a>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="ag_photo_download_button" onclik="yourFunction">Download Photo</button>
```

Comment: `onclik` is spelled wrong and inline HTML event handlers are not suggested as they don't follow standards, create spaghetti code and create global anonymous wrapper functions around the event attribute's code.

Comment: I tried it before asking the question and sadly it didn't work either

Answer (score -1):

try binding the event to `document` instead

```
$(document).on( "click", '#download,#ag_photo_download_button', function() {
alert('hey there')
});
```

this way it doesn't matter if the element are present in DOM or not,  `.on()` will fail if the element you're trying to bind to doesn't exist yet. using `$(document).ready(function(){}` is another option.

#### Also

make sure there isn't another element with the same id in your full code.

Comment: Doesn't work either :/ I checked and i don't any other element with the same id